# Rotate an object to view it from every angle in 3D

Tags: 3d, rotation, directx

I'm using DirectX, and the setup of camera and stuff is already there. The camera is looking at an object that I want to rotate so that it is viewed from every angle.

When rendering the object a matrix is created by multiplying rotation and translation matrices. The rotation matrix I have now is created with XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw(x,y,z).

Is there a way of setting x,y,z so that I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory you can just do three nested `for` loops running from 0 degrees to 180 degrees for each of yaw, pitch, and roll (since `XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw` takes radians and not degrees so actually run from 0 to XM_PI radians).

> Note, however, you may run into [gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) problems using Euler angles, which is why quaternions are often used for camera rotation controls.

Of course, this assumes you want to see the object from every single-degree angle. If you just want to make sure every part of the object is visible, you can do that with larger increments of say 45 degrees (XM_PI / 4.f radians).

And you will end up with some duplications since you can combine different Euler angles to produce the same 3D rotation.